# Will I receive an RT call or am I safe?

Tags: stocks, shorting-securities, margin-call

I just opened a position on WeBull to short a stock with a market value of $1,554. The total amount of cash in my account is $5200, but my day trading and overnight buying power is saying 0 after I open my position. Will I receive an RT call if I hold this overnight or will I be covered on this position with the amount of cash in my account?

Is it my equity/cash or buying power which needs to be 50 percent of $1,554 that I have tied up in the stock?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Standard Reg T margin is 50% so the requirement for shorting a stock with a market value of $1,554 could be $777.  Why did I say could be?

- Stocks below $5 are not marginable
- Leveraged ETFs have a higher margin requirement
- Brokers can have a higher margin requirement than Reg T
- Some of your cash could be tied up by other margined option or stock positions

Therefore, I can't really answer your question because there are other possible mitigating factors.